# Does Fedex Support/Provide Shipment Invoice Report via api

Tags: php, fedex

background:
Typically FedEx's initial shipment buying cost and after invoice cost is identical. But sometimes, even though the initial shipping label charge is the same but after delivery, FedEx invoice a different amount for address correction, residential address, etc.

My Question :
Does FedEx provide shipment invoiced reports after billing adjustment via webhook?

(if yes, how does it work? Need explanation in PHP). if no, how do you handle it right now

Answer (score 0):

Billing data is not available via API. The best solution is to take FedEx electronic billing data (delimited) and reconcile on a weekly basis.